# How to make object of solr search in editor of main template?

Tags: solr, typo3, typoscript

I have successfully managed to use SOLR Search in my TYPO3 installation. I am using TYPO3 7.6.10 SOLR 6.5.0 and SOLR plugin 6.1.0 
 What Typoscript should I use to make object of this plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the basic Solr TypoScript.[image: Solr Base configuration]

Comment: I want to write typoscript in the editor so that i can add this to my HTML template like this **<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.search" />**

Comment: Ah, you want the search form in the frontend? You can use `plugin.tx_solr_PiResults_Results` to get the default search form.